# Will the warning about asking disappear if I get more reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, asking-questions, post-ban

I got the following warning:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.
>
> For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question?
>
> Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

I know I have asked some stupid questions.

**My question is**: my current reputation is 60. If my reputation increases to 300, will this warning disappear?

Comment: Only if you ask better, well-received questions.

Comment: @Oded my question is whether stackoverflow has the mechanism to cancel this warning, or i will see this warning forever

Comment: If you start asking better, well-received questions, you will stop getting the warning. Nothing to do with reputation.

Comment: you mean system consider my new question, right? please tell me whether "better question" == "more up-vote question"

Comment: Well - yes. If the community votes a question up, it is considered a better question than one that didn't get any votes or has a negative score. Note that we do have voting fraud detection - if someone is caught trying to artificially get votes on their posts, they can get suspended.

Answer (score 6):

The warning is not reputation-dependent.

Of the [questions you've asked](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3370849/roroco?tab=questions&sort=votes), you've had some recent very well-received questions (e.g., [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26728333/1234256)), as well as some not-so-well-received questions (e.g., [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26774677/1234256)). If you keep asking good questions such as the former, the message will disappear.